# RF cavity Field Maps using Poisson Superfish

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, maxwell-equations, software

This may be a slightly obscure question but I'm trying to use [Poisson Superfish](http://laacg.lanl.gov/laacg/services/download_sf.phtml) to generate field maps for single cell of an ILC SRF Cavity.  There are examples in the documentation for radio frequency tuning, and also for magnetostatics and electrostatics, but no radio frequency case.

Is it possible to solve magnetic field statically, and electric field statically (i.e independent of one another )and then tack on a sinusoidal oscilator ($\pi /2$ out of phase with one another) and thus give me a vector of six field components: ($B_x, \, B_y, \, B_z, \, E_x, \, E_y, \, E_z$)? Am I even asking Poisson Super right questions, i.e can it solve the problem I have or am I asking it do something it was never meant to do?

Failing that does anyone know of a good method for finding these field maps (i.e from a different program).  Note:  I am very poor and cannot afford ANSYS or whatever it is the big dogs use.  I would not typically ask such a question here  but the documentation for Superfish is atrocious (probably due to its age) and what little there is doesn't even render properly for me.